# Refreshing PyQt4 window

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

Hey I am trying to refresh the GUI window, but for some reason it does not refresh till all of the loops are finished. I read the other posts and tried their solutions but they didnt help. Can someone spot the thing that I did wrong or what I should add? The code is below, reads certain values from a json file and stores them in the GUI table. I am using PyQt4 and python 2.7. Thank you in advance.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import time
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
import json
import threading

from GUI_Window import *
LastCommandTime=0

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
      QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
      self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
      self.ui.setupUi(self)
      self.ui.button.clicked.connect(self.DataCollection)
   def DataCollection(self):
      print "button clicked"
      task1=threading.Thread(target=self.DisplayCommand)
      task1.start()
      task2=threading.Thread(target=self.DisplayTemp)
      task2.start()
      task1.join()
      task2.join()
   def DisplayCommand(self):
      start=time.time()
      with open("20170602153617003.log") as f:
         for line in f:
            data = []
            data=json.loads(line)
            try:
                if data['TYPE']== "             cmd":
                    command= data["command"]
                    print "1"
                    self.ui.command_table.setItem(0,0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(command["cmd_name"]))
                    self.ui.command_table.setItem(0,1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(command["opcode"]))
                    self.ui.command_table.setItem(0,2, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("".join((str(x)+',') for x in command["param_type_list"])))
                    self.ui.command_table.setItem(0,3, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("".join((str(x)+',') for x in command["param_val_list"])))
                    self.ui.commands_time.display((time.time()-start))
                    start=time.time()
                    time.sleep(1)
                if data['TYPE']== "       cmd_reply":
                    command= data["response"]
                    self.ui.reply_table.setItem(0,0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data["cmd_name"].replace(" ","")))
                    self.ui.reply_table.setItem(0,1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("0x%02x"%command["opcode"]))
                    self.ui.reply_table.setItem(0,2, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(command["error_control_type"])))
                    self.ui.reply_table.setItem(0,3, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(command["data_present"])))
                    self.ui.reply_table.setItem(0,4, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(command["command_reply"])))
                    self.ui.reply_table.setItem(0,5, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(command["status_flags"])))
                    self.ui.reply_table.setItem(0,6, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(command["condition_code"])))
                    self.ui.reply_table.setItem(0,7, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(command["data_length"])))
                    self.ui.reply_table.setItem(0,8, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(command["data"])))
                    self.ui.reply_table.setItem(0,9, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(command["error_control"])))
                    flags=command['flags']
                    self.ui.replyflg_table.setItem(0,0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(flags["BOOT_FAIL"])))
                    self.ui.replyflg_table.setItem(0,1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(flags["BOOT_SOURCE"])))
                    self.ui.replyflg_table.setItem(0,2, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(flags["COMM_SIDE"])))
                    self.ui.replyflg_table.setItem(0,3, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(flags["SELF_TEST_FAIL"])))
                    self.ui.replyflg_table.setItem(0,4, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(flags["STA_ERROR"])))
                    self.ui.replyflg_table.setItem(0,5, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(flags["SPECTROMETER_ERROR"])))
                    self.ui.replyflg_table.setItem(0,6, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(flags["SCCD_READY"])))
                    self.ui.replyflg_table.setItem(0,7, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(flags["SCANNER_ON"])))
                    self.ui.replyflg_table.setItem(0,8, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(flags["SCANNER_COMM_ERROR"])))
                    self.ui.replyflg_table.setItem(0,9, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(flags["SCANNER_HOME_ERROR"])))
                    self.ui.replyflg_table.setItem(0,10, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(flags["ERROR_LOG_NOT_EMPTY"])))
                    self.ui.replyflg_table.setItem(0,11, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(flags["SEND_EVR"])))
                    self.ui.replyflg_table.setItem(0,12, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(flags["SYS_ERROR"])))
                    self.ui.replyflg_table.setItem(0,13, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(flags["UNDEFINED0"])))
                    self.ui.replyflg_table.setItem(0,14, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(flags["UNDEFINED1"])))
                time.sleep(.1)
            except KeyError:
                time.sleep(.1)
                pass
            QApplication.processEvents() 

    def DisplayTemp(self):
       i=0
       while i<10:
           print "hi"
           self.ui.flt_table.setItem(0,0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(i)))
           i=i+1
           QApplication.processEvents() 
           time.sleep(.2)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    graphTimer = QtCore.QTimer()
    graphTimer.timeout.connect(app.processEvents)
    graphTimer.start(0.1)
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Also it appears that if I comment out the DisplayTemp() then it works just fine. I was thinking that the number of threads might be causing trouble but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Having the QApplication,processEvents() before the sem.release() does not help in case that was an option.

Comment: Also, where do you acquire the semaphore?

Comment: I'm not sure. It just caused issues when I set a place where I was acquiring it and taking that part out seemed to make things work better

Comment: Then get rid of the semaphore entirely.

Comment: Okay but they werent the cause of the problem

Comment: Probably not, but your goal is to present a minimal working example that illustrates the problem, not make us slog through lines of irrelevant code.

Comment: Okay sorry. I took all the semaphore stuff out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was caused by the .join commands. They are blocking so apparently they stop the GUI from refreshing at some level. I hope this helps someone out in the future.